# Angular 5 pattern validation is not working with dynamic reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to achieve field validation with angular reactive forms with regex pattern `##.##.##.##`. For some patterns, it is not working. I tried the below input `12.25.36.25` which fails the validation, tested the pattern `(^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}$)` with [regextester](https://www.regextester.com/) which works fine. I am not sure the what's going wrong here. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkrrhs-hjibh3).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you forgot to add a field in `class question-base` called `pattern`.
Here is the code:

```
export class QuestionBase<T> {
  ...
  pattern: string;

  constructor(options: {
      ...
      pattern?: string
    } = {}) {
    ...
    this.pattern = options.pattern || null
  }
}
```

Another problem is that ##.##.##.## is not a valid number. You need to change that input to be of type `text`. Lastly if your pattern is a regular expression you need to use javascript's regex type instead of string. Replace your pattern to be `/^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}$/`

Edit: Final form of model should be:

```
new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'version',
        label: 'Release Number',
        type: 'text',
        required: true,
        order: 4,
        pattern: /^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}$/ // needed format: ##.##.##.##
 })
```

Comment: I did two more changes that I forgot to mention. `25.25.25.25` is not a valid number but it's of type `text`. Also I changed the pattern inside the service from `'^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}$'` to `/^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}$/`. Dunno why string does not work but regex does. Updated my answer.

Comment: the requirement is i dont want user to enter the text/characters in the input element and the reason i am accessing the pattern from other file is, pattern will be varied based on the user logged-in and account type he has access to.

Comment: Added more code to make it clear on how I made it work.

Comment: hey, could you please save the link?, i can't see your code

Comment: All changed code is in the answer but I also saved the link if you want to see a working example.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkrrhs-8cdzcz